# Google Maps on Ionic Framework/Cordova not working on android build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have been writing code for an app to track user location and display it using Google Maps.

My code works perfectly in browsers (Safari,Firefox,Chrome) but doesn't work at all on mobile (android).

The google maps api doesn't work and the navigation is unreliable. I'm a ionic newbie and wrote a fairly simple app to test it out. It has got ionic side menu template with some simple AngularJS controller.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

        // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
        // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
        // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
        // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
        //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
        //});

        // Form data for the login modal
        $scope.loginData = {};

        // Create the login modal that we will use later
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });

        // Triggered in the login modal to close it
        $scope.closeLogin = function() {
            $scope.modal.hide();
        };

        // Open the login modal
        $scope.login = function() {
            $scope.modal.show();
        };

        // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
        $scope.doLogin = function() {
            console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

            // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
            // code if using a login system
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.closeLogin();
            }, 1000);
        };
    })

    .controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.playlists = [
            { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
            { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
            { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
            { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
            { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
            { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
        ];
    })

    .controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    })

    .controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
        console.log("MapController");
        $scope.initialise = function() {
            console.log("In Google.maps.event.addDomListener");
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 19,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            console.log(mapOptions);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                console.log(pos);
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
                var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                    map: map,
                    title: "My Location"
                });
            });

            $scope.map = map;
        };
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.initialise());


    });
```

Check all code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Saumik/ionicgooglemaps). Any help on this would be appreciated.

The error displaying on my developer console:

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

Comment: 404 page not found, also include some relevant code here and maybe set up a working plnkr / codepen

Comment: @MarkVeenstra Here is the link to the controller https://github.com/Saumik/ionicgooglemaps/blob/master/www/js/controllers.js Also fixed up the above link,

Comment: Any errors in the developer console? You can debug a Cordova app on a phone using chrome://inspect#devices

Comment: @MarkVeenstra Here are the errors I see in the console http://s22.postimg.org/th9ekqw0x/Screen_Shot_2015_06_09_at_1_02_23_pm.png

Comment: Did my answer solve your issues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Error states that `google` is undefined. My best educated guess would be that the script from the `index.html` is not loaded correctly:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD4bzp0Ck8nTXgfs9ZYo8vXZ2tgWhqzWmY&sensor=true">
```

I think this is because of the new Cordova 5.0 release being used. You need to install the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` as following:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Also add the following to `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Finally add the following to your `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">
```

Be aware that above settings are not settings you want to have in a production environment. Please take a look at the [README](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#cordova-plugin-whitelist) of the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` to learn more.

Comment: Sorry bro tried it but it shows a white screen without the map. No change tried what you wrote here. Got the same problem in ios emulate too

Comment: Hey wait just changed the placement of the script tag and played with the css. It has started working thanks btw though1

Comment: hello did you find a solution for that ?? i have the same issue

Comment: Almost give up until I cam across your answer thank you

Comment: For the people who are still struggling to get this working, here is how i did it. It is about the placement of the script. Do not put the script inside the head of the index.html. take it out and put it just before the body tag starts. cheers!